# Is there an opposite method for RemoveAt?

Tags: c#

```
private void btnSzures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
    {
        string a = txtszuro.Text;
        if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(a))
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do the opposite thing with this `btnSzures_Click`. So it would add these lines not remove them. Is there a similar method where i would just need to correct a few things in this code?

Comment: `ListBox.Items.Insert`?

Comment: There is an Insert method that could take an index but it is not clear what are you trying to do. The list exists and you want to insert a new element inside this list at specific position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technical "opposite" of `RemoveAt()` is `Insert(int index, string item)`. This allows you to insert the `item` into the `Items` collection that you have beginning at the specified index.

Comment: this isn't even a complete sentence

Comment: @johnny5 It is now.

Comment: @juharr  this went from 3 down votes to three up votes, I'm wondering if this was a well executed ploy to flip votes, but he's got my vote now so well played